# OSError: cannot open resource

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, font-face

```
import tkinter as tk  
from tkinter import ttk,font  
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont

root = tk.Tk()

def func_image():  
    image = Image.open(r'E:\side_300.png')  
    font_type_1 = ImageFont.truetype(str(combo.get()),18)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)  
    draw.text((50,50),text='Hello',fill='red',font=font_type_1)  
    image.show()  

fonts=list(font.families())  
fonts.sort()  
combo = ttk.Combobox(root,value=fonts)    
combo.pack()  

btn = ttk.Button(root,text='Click Me',command=func_image)  
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Output**

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Mevada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__return self.func(*args)
>   File "test.py", line 9, in func_image
>   font_type_1 = ImageFont.truetype(str(combo.get()),18)
>   File "C:\Users\Mevada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 280, in truetype return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
>   File "C:\Users\Mevada\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 145, in __init__layout_engine=layout_engine)
>   OSError: cannot open resource

**Thanks...**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk  
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

root = tk.Tk()

def func_image():  
    image = Image.open(r'E:\side_300.png')  
    font_type_1 = ImageFont.truetype(fm.findfont(fm.FontProperties(family=combo.get())),18)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)  
    draw.text((50,50),text='Hello',fill='red',font=font_type_1)  
    image.show()  

fonts = list(set([f.name for f in fm.fontManager.ttflist]))
fonts.sort()

combo = ttk.Combobox(root,value=fonts)    
combo.pack()  

btn = ttk.Button(root,text='Click Me',command=func_image)  
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow, congratulations! I looked all over for that solution, but couldn't find it. And, by the way, I've just read your solution and I think you can change these lines so your code becomes more readable:
`font_type_1 = ImageFont.truetype(fonts[combo.get()],18)`, `fonts = dict([(f.name,f.fname) for f in fm.fontManager.ttflist])` and `combo = ttk.Combobox(root,value=sorted(fonts.keys()))    
`

Comment: @RafaelBarros Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I forgot to mention to remove this line `fonts.sort()` in the suggestion.

Comment: @RafaelBarros I did it :)

Answer (score 0):

`ImageFont.truetype` requires that you give it a filename. You're not giving it a filename, you're giving it the name of a font family. Tkinter's `font.families()` does not return filenames.

Comment: So, is there any module which helps me to return font file name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `font` cannot be found by PIL.

Find your font file in your computer. In windows, it always in `C:\WINDOWS\Fonts` directory. select one and modify your line 9 like it:

```
font_type_1 = ImageFont.truetype("bahnschrift.ttf",18)
```

`bahnschrift.ttf` is just a sample on my computer, I am not sure it exists on your computer.

Comment: Yes it is possible.But, I want to provide a combo box for changing the font. Is there any module which helps me to get filename of a font?

Comment: @BhaveshMevada you can DIY with `os`, just open `C:\WINDOWS\Fonts` path get all filename then you get all available font. You can customize anything for your want after it.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you have to insert the font filename as the first argument here: `ImageFont.truetype(str(combo.get()),18)`.

If you try, for example, **arial**, you will succeed (if you have Arial installed on your computer, of course). Oh, and that function is case sensitive, so you have to write it in lowercase, because the filename is actually *arial.ttf* (you can drop the extension if want, by the way).

So, your combo box isn't working because when you choose a font named *Courier New*, for example, PIL won't find it, because its filename is *cour.ttf*. Unfortunately, you can't use that list of fonts from tkinter on ImageFont and I don't have a workaround for you in that case.

As I said, this might work, but you have to let go of your combo box: `ImageFont.truetype('arial',18)`

Before I go, one more important note: if  you are working on a OS other than Windows, you have to type the full path to the font file.